# Помогите исправить TypeError: client.guilds.resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord-api

Доброго вечера уважаемые стакеры. Возникла проблема с дискорд ботом (discord.js v11.5.0) уже все версии перетыкал, во всех ранних версиях одна и та же ошибка. Для тех, кто больше меня понимает в этом, помогите пожалуйста :)
Собственно сама **ошибка:**

```
Logged in as MAFIA Westeros#9993!
C:\DiscordMafiaGame\index.js:66
  gamedata.guild = client.guilds.resolve(tokenFile.guildId);
                                 ^

TypeError: client.guilds.resolve is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\index.js:66:34)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:141:61)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildCreate.js:13:31)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\DiscordMafiaGame\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Файл **index.js:**

```
        gamedata.guild = client.guilds.resolve(tokenFile.guildId);
  if (!gamedata.guild) {
    console.error("Invalid guild id in token file.");
    return;
  }

  gamedata.townchat = gamedata.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "town-chat");
  gamedata.mafiachat = gamedata.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "mafia-chat");
  gamedata.doctorchat = gamedata.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "doctor-chat");
  gamedata.deadchat = gamedata.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "dead-chat");
  gamedata.sheriffchat = gamedata.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "sheriff-chat");
```

**console.log(client.guilds)**

```
C:\DiscordMafiaGame>node index.js
Logged in as MAFIA Westeros#9993!
Collection(1) [Map] {
  '1044215355410763837' => Guild {
    members: Collection(1) [Map] { '1053299489072484382' => [GuildMember] },
    channels: Collection(27) [Map] {
      '1044215360179671060' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1044215360179671061' => [TextChannel],
      '1044215360179671062' => [TextChannel],
      '1044215360179671063' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1044215360179671064' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1044215360179671065' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1050819217487843410' => [TextChannel],
      '1051015731933872179' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1051015816558157845' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1051015983562752031' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1051016051770527784' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1051016147941736490' => [TextChannel],
      '1051016383741313094' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1051435000412786688' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1051739191966433291' => [TextChannel],
      '1052447612537683978' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1052447699854696449' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1052518319913185334' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1052518764828168193' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1052518863989915659' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1052519198380785687' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1052519309806665788' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1053296228236009563' => [TextChannel],
      '1053301758115450951' => [CategoryChannel],
      '1053301944237686805' => [VoiceChannel],
      '1053319380886364201' => [TextChannel],
      '1053336599292825620' => [TextChannel]
    },
    roles: Collection(13) [Map] {
      '1044215355410763837' => [Role],
      '1050743782108307456' => [Role],
      '1050782350734262272' => [Role],
      '1050782651381981184' => [Role],
      '1050783045931769918' => [Role],
      '1051122452278804540' => [Role],
      '1051122711650377758' => [Role],
      '1051432039435477053' => [Role],
      '1053295683278479423' => [Role],
      '1053296296708018297' => [Role],
      '1053304566755622952' => [Role],
      '1053319170026115162' => [Role],
      '1053648451495280665' => [Role]
    },
    presences: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    deleted: false,
    available: true,
    id: '1044215355410763837',
    name: 'Вестерос',
    icon: '4432d180d4fad7ef0cb3084b5ff8042a',
    splash: null,
    region: 'deprecated',
    memberCount: 38,
    large: false,
    features: [ 'APPLICATION_COMMAND_PERMISSIONS_V2' ],
    applicationID: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelID: null,
    systemChannelID: '1044215360179671061',
    embedEnabled: undefined,
    verificationLevel: 0,
    explicitContentFilter: 0,
    mfaLevel: 0,
    joinedTimestamp: 1671279766775,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
    ownerID: '835499059388481607',
    _rawVoiceStates: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    emojis: Collection(0) [Map] {}
  }
}
```

Посмотрел репозиторий разработчика данного бота, примерно прикинул год, месяц и нарыл версию discord.js, но оно отказывается работать как хотелось бы. Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь

Comment: Ошибка говорит сама за себя `client.guilds.resolve` - не функция. Посмотрите, что лежит в `client.guilds`

Comment: @swad ой, это снова вы :) Да вот как раз таки и не могу найти client.guilds

Comment: Ищите, что такое у вас `client` - смотрите импорты. Наверняка это импорт какого то пакета. Так же смотрите package.json, возможно там указаны нужные версии библиотек. Далее можно только теоретически помочь. Найти библиотеку, обновить, переписать под новую функциональность

Comment: @Swad Вместо импорта здесь const client = new Discord.Client(); больше ничего нет. Не знаю как вам показать содержимое package.json в комментарии. https://pastebin.com/669zBrDj

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос, нажав кнопку "Править" ниже вопроса. `const client = new Discord.Client();` - Вот далее, перед ошибкой, напишите `console.log(client.guilds)` и посмотрите, что там вообще лежит. Так же поищите, где **Discord** у вас инициализируется

Comment: @SwaD Все что выдал лог добавил в конце правки. Инициализация в том же месте, где и client const Discord = require('discord.js');

Comment: Как вы видите, там нет функции `resolve`. Что эта функция когда либо делала... ктож его знает. Скорее всего надо сесть за документацию и почитать, что там к чему + осмыслить свой код, который пытаетесь запустить. Конечно, возможно, тут найдутся те, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает как ее решить, но я вам рекомендую не тратить время зря и пойти заново знакомиться с данной библиотекой.

Comment: @SwaD Честно, я тоже обыскался. Я не особо разбираюсь в этом, поэтому поверхностным взглядом прошёлся, понимание какое-никакое имею. Комментарий к данной строчке такой   // Finds guild and channels that are needed for the game

Но как оно работало и работало ли вообще и почему если не работало, то делает ошибку сейчас не понятно..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function или Cannot read property \*\*\* of undefined or null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-cannot-re)